# Getting specific data of a specific record from a file with C

Tags: c

I have a method called AddOrder() where the user creates an order. As the system asks the user to enter Product Name, I want to write a function that gets the specific record from the products.dat file. Also as the user is asked to enter the amount of product quantity, I want the system to be able to detect if the product quantity of that particular product exceeds the amount available in Stock(also stored in products.dat) of that product.

I tried the function but it is not working properly when I call it from AddOrder(). Here's my code.

```
void addOrder()
{
    order o1;


    ofp=fopen("orders.dat","ab");


    printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\t Adding an Order\n\n");
    printf("========================================================\n\n");

    do
    {
        printf("Enter CustomerID: \n");
        scanf("%s",&o1.CustomerID);
    }while(!findCustomer(o1.CustomerID));


    printf("Enter Product Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", o1.ProductName);

    int QuantityInStock = getQuantity(o1.ProductName);
    printf("%d", &QuantityInStock);

    int PQuantity = 0;
    printf("Enter Product Quantities: \n");
    scanf("%d", &PQuantity);

    if(PQuantity > QuantityInStock)
    {
        printf("You have axeceeded available stock!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Product Quantity is available\n");
    }

    fwrite(&o1,sizeof(o1),1,ofp);
    printf("Order record was added to the system!\n");
    fclose(ofp);
}

int getQuantity(const char* ProductName)
{
    FILE *pfp;
    product p;
    int countstock=0;

    pfp=fopen("products.dat","rb");

    while(1)
    {
        fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,pfp);

        if(feof(pfp))
        {
        break;
        }
        if(strcmp(ProductName,p.ProductName)==0)
        {
            countstock +=&p.QuantityInStock;
        }

    }

    fclose(pfp);
    return countstock;

}
```

Comment: What errors you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf("%d", &QuantityInStock);`

Why are using `&` while printing `QuantityInStock` value, it will print the address of `QuantityInStock` variable not its value..

`printf("%d", QuantityInStock);`

I think this is not the answer of your problem, problem is some where else..Please share the error you are getting..

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved. It was & that was getting the address not the actual value. I used printf to test it and a huge value was printed.